# C# wpf Sql Table, encrypted passwords

Tags: c#, sql, encryption

I am working with a application when user can login in the program by typing their information. Passwords are stored in table as encrypted. But when i try to login using this password it doesn't work.\

For encrypting data I use this stored procedure

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[inn]
   @use varchar (50) = null,
   @ins varchar (50) = null

 AS


   INSERT INTO [kole].[dbo].[koll]
       ([Userr]
      ,[ins])


 VALUES
        (@use,
       ((EncryptByPassPhrase('8', @ins)))
```

And for decrypte I use this stored Procedure

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[sle]
 @Use varchar (50) = null,
 @ins varchar (50) = null

 AS
 SELECT Userr,CONVERT(varchar(50),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('8',ins)) as Password
FROM [kole].[dbo].[koll]
 where Userr = @Use and ins = @ins

   GO
```

In c# I use this code for calling data, and log in into program.

```
              private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = kole; Integrated Security = true");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sle", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userr", txt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ins", psw.Password);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            if (count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This user don't exist");
                SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
                txt.Text = "";
                psw.Password = "";

            }
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Granted!");
                SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
                conn.Open();
    }
```

How can I decrypt the password in correct way , to use for login into program. Thanks

Comment: Apart from the problem: dd you consider hashing instead of encryption?

Comment: how can i do this, could you tell me with a sample cause i am new

Comment: I think these websites pretty much tells you the why's and the how's (https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm / http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608860/Understanding-and-Implementing-Password-Hashing). In short, its better not to be able to retrieve the password, in case the website leaks information somehow.

Comment: @Caramirel , but how can i use the encrypted password for log in, cauese you said, it'n not good to retrieve the password

Comment: When the user registers, the password gets 'scrambled' in a specific way (hashed). Then, if the user decides to login, the password gets scrambled in the exact same way. If they match up, the password was correct.

Comment: The parameter names ir the stored procedure must match the c# code.  Here is one error : "@Userr"  (the stored procedure has nor r's and is lower case).

Comment: I would run some searches and read a bunch of articles for yourself.  keep in mind is that you can and depending on application should use your application layer to do the encryption so that both your encryption mode and decryption mode don't reside in your database. If a hacker gets your database they can un encrypt the sensitive data in it.  So don't store passphrase anywhere in database. Adding salt like link discusses is good.  Look for symmetric encryption examples.  Hashing is often suggested so you cannot reverse and unencrypt to get the clear text password.....

Answer (score 0):

Passwords should not be saved encrypted because they are retrievable. Instead they should be hashed, a cryptographic hash is a one-way function that can not be reversed. On entry the password is hashed and the hashed value entered into the DB. On verification the password to be verified is hashed in the same manner and that compared to the hashed value in the DB.

By "hash" above the following is meant: Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Quite simply, assuming an app that is used by the general public and which the users expect good security you really need to consult with a security domain expert, don;t wait until after the attack.

Finally use good two-factor authentication and keep good control over all server administrators.

Answer (score 0):

In your [dbo].[sle] stored procedure, you need

```
SET @ins = EncryptByPassPhrase('8', @ins)
```